# Множественный классификатор на несбалансированных данных

Tags: r, статистика, машинное-обучение

Нужно построить множественный классификатор (5 классов) на сильно несбалансированной выборке.

```
> table(d$class)
    0   0.3   0.5   0.7     1 
12385   736   733    25  1869
```

Если просто запустить `RandomForest`, то ничего получается.
Значит, надо как-то её балансировать. А вот этого я делать-то и не умею.
Все найденные пакеты по балансировке предполагают лишь бинарную классификацию.
Смотрел пакеты:

- unbalanced
- ROSE

Читал [эту статью](http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/666.pdf).

Думал, может в самом `RandomForest` есть возможность задать cost или сэмплинг — тоже не нашлось. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Пробовали строить отдельные модели по принципу "один против всех"? Можно сначала научиться выделять, например, самый редкий класс (остальные 4 при этом будут объединены в один).

Comment: Тема раскрыта в книге http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/978-5-97060-273-7/, глава 3. Оригинал на английском (http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/computer-science/pattern-recognition-and-machine-learning/machine-learning-art-and-science-algorithms-make-sense-data) можно нагуглить.

Comment: @Ogurtsov А принципиально выделять самый редкий класс сначала? Я бы наоборот, поймал сначала самый популярный класс ("0") - научился бы выделять его, и затем просто откинул бы из обучающего множества. То есть последующие обучения я бы проводил "не один против 4", а "один против 3". Или так нельзя вообще делать ?

Comment: А попробуйте, сравните разные подходы (без примера данных никто ничего не проверит при всем желании). Завтра попробую запостить выдержку из книги, на которую ссылаюсь, это должно добавить ясности.

Comment: У меня есть эта книга. Но непонятно, как с помощью леса прогнозировать положительные и отрицательные случаи...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В пакете "caret" существуют две функции: `upSample()` и `downSample()`, которые решают эту проблему. Балансировать классы необходимо независимо от применяемых методов классификации.

**Обновление**

Если отвечать широко,то нужно указать, что балансировка классов один из многих важных этапов, которые нужно выполнить прежде чем начать обучать модель. Просто перечислю: выбор и оценка входных переменных, разделение на тренировочную и тестовую выборку(желательно стратифицированную), балансировка классов(только тренировочного набора), препроцессинг (нормализация,стандартизация и т.л.), перемешивание тренировочного набора и др. От качества проведения этих работ на 80% зависит качество получаемого результата моделирования.

Если отвечать так широко потребуется статья хорошего объема. Необходимость балансировки классов подтверждается многочисленными экспериментами (не только моими) с многими моделями. Просто сравните результаты классификации одинаковых наборов с и без балансировки Вы убедитесь в этом сами..

Answer (score 3):

Вот такая функция решает эту проблему

```
my.strata <- function(v) {
  tmp <- as.vector(table(v));
  num_clases <- length(tmp);
  min_size <- tmp[order(tmp,decreasing=FALSE)[1]];
  rep(min_size,num_clases);
}


randomForest(.... sampsize=my.strata( ) ... )
```